# drawing a regular hexagon

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \newdimen\R
\R=2.7cm
   \draw (0:\R)
   \foreach \x in {60,120,...,360} {  -- (\x:\R) }
 -- cycle (360:\R) node[right] {(3,2,1)}
 -- cycle (300:\R) node[below] {(3,1,2)}
      -- cycle (240:\R) node[below] {(1,3,2)}
 -- cycle (180:\R) node[left] {(1,2,3)}
-- cycle  (120:\R) node[above] {(2,1,3)}

           -- cycle  (60:\R) node[above] {(2,3,1)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have to draw small circles at the corners of this hexagon filled with black color.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \newdimen\R
   \R=2.7cm
   \draw (0:\R) \foreach \x in {60,120,...,360} {  -- (\x:\R) };
   \foreach \x/\l/\p in
     { 60/{(2,3,1)}/above,
      120/{(2,1,3)}/above,
      180/{(1,2,3)}/left,
      240/{(1,3,2)}/below,
      300/{(3,1,2)}/below,
      360/{(3,2,1)}/right
     }
     \node[inner sep=1pt,circle,draw,fill,label={\p:\l}] at (\x:\R) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** As additionally requested, now with arrows in the middle of the sides, a circular arrow in the middle, and all sorts of labels. The arrows in the middle require the tikz library `decorations.markings`. The library `arrows` has been just loaded to get a fancier arrow head; without this library, replace `stealth'` by `>` (two times), doesn't look bad either. Moreover, I chose the option `thick` to add more weight to the lines

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [thick
  ,decoration =
    {markings
    ,mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth'}}
    }
  ]
  \newdimen\R
  \R=2.7cm
  \node {X};
  \draw[-stealth'] (-150:{0.7*\R}) arc (-150:150:{0.7*\R});
  \foreach \x/\l in
    { 60/a,
     120/b,
     180/c,
     240/d,
     300/e,
     360/f
    }
    \draw[postaction={decorate}] ({\x-60}:\R) -- node[auto,swap]{\l} (\x:\R);
  \foreach \x/\l/\p in
    { 60/{(2,3,1)}/above,
     120/{(2,1,3)}/above,
     180/{(1,2,3)}/left,
     240/{(1,3,2)}/below,
     300/{(3,1,2)}/below,
     360/{(3,2,1)}/right
    }
    \node[inner sep=2pt,circle,draw,fill,label={\p:\l}] at (\x:\R) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sir, I have to orient the sides of this hexagon by drawing the left arrow heads on the middle of the sides and I have to orient the whole Hexagon by drawing $\currvearrowleft$ at the center of the hexagon. Need your help sir @gernot

Comment: @ShahnawazAhmad I've added the arrows.

Comment: Sorry sir for asking so many questions. What to do if i have to label the sides of the hexagon and the whole hexagon at the center @ gernot

Comment: @ShahnawazAhmad I've added labels.

Comment: Dear Sir, in case, I have to draw the diagonals(connecting corner 213 with 132)in first figure, what necessary changes I have to make in the code -@ gernot

Comment: @ShahnawazAhmad Do you mean something like `\draw (120:\R) -- (240:\R);` added before `\end{tikzpicture}`?

Answer (score 12):

The following example implements the hexagon as node with shape of a regular polygon.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
  \tikz\path
    node[
      regular polygon,
      regular polygon sides=6,
      draw,
      inner sep=1.7cm,
    ] (hexagon) {}
    %
    % Annotations
    (hexagon.corner 1) node[above] {$(2,3,1)$}
    (hexagon.corner 2) node[above] {$(2,1,3)$}
    (hexagon.corner 3) node[left] {$(1,2,3)$}
    (hexagon.corner 4) node[below] {$(1,3,2)$}
    (hexagon.corner 5) node[below] {$(3,1,2)$}
    (hexagon.corner 6) node[right] {$(3,2,1)$}
    %
    % Small filled black circles
    plot[
      mark=*,
      samples at={1, ..., 6},
    ] (hexagon.corner \x)
  ;
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Sir, I have to orient the sides of this hexagon by drawing the left arrow heads on the middle of the sides and I have to orient the whole Hexagon by drawing $\currvearrowleft$ at the center of the hexagon. Need your help sir @
Heiko Oberdiek

Answer (score 3):

Is this helping you:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\R}\setlength{\R}{2.7cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  %% Try to define a style, to prevent typing
  [inner sep=2mm,
  minicirc/.style={circle,draw=black!20,fill=black!20,thick}]

  %% Now do the circle with nodes
  \node (circ1) at ( 60:\R) [minicirc] {(2,3,1)};
  \node (circ2) at (120:\R) [minicirc] {(2,3,1)};
  \node (circ3) at (180:\R) [minicirc] {(2,3,1)};
  \node (circ4) at (240:\R) [minicirc] {(2,3,1)};
  \node (circ5) at (300:\R) [minicirc] {(2,3,1)};
  \node (circ6) at (360:\R) [minicirc] {(2,3,1)};

  %% Connect those circs
  \draw [thick] (circ1) to (circ2) to (circ3) 
  to (circ4) to (circ5) to (circ6) to (circ1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(This was my first attempt on TikZ :-)  Thank you)

This is the result:

[image]

I've tried this first with your loop.  But it seems, as if the names of the elements ("circ1", ...) are local to the loop and hence can't be addressed from outside the loop.   So I did it manually without loop.

If the color of the circles doesn't suit you, you can easily change its definition in the style.  Maybe you'll have to set the color of the text to be white ...

Comment: I don't know what you did with the loop, but node names are not local to the it. Try for example replacing your six `\node`s with `\foreach[count=\i] \x in {60,120,...,360}   \node (circ\i) at (\x:\R) [minicirc] {(2,3,1)};`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: I didn't get it to work (it was my first attempt on TikZ).  Seeing this solutions, I now tried: `%% Now do the circle with nodes
  \foreach \x in {60,120,...,360} {
    \node (circ\x) at (\x:\R) [minicirc] {(2,3,1)};
  }
  %% Connect those circs
  \draw [thick] (circ60) to (circ120) to (circ180) 
  to (circ240) to (circ300) to (circ360) to (circ60);` and this works :-)  Thank you very much.